# attach drop target to dragged object

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

In **Kineticjs** is it possible to attach a **droptarget** to the element being dragged.
I need to highlight the target when *drop* happens.
The code i am using is

```
circle.on("dragstart", function(e) { layer.draw();});
 circle.on("dragmove", function(e) {cosnole.log("drag move");});
circle.on('dragend', function(e) {cosnole.log("drag end");});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't say much about the drop target, what you have already done? these are just event handlers. So trying to understand... you want to highlight another KineticJS object when this circle is moved, but is the circle downloadable only in that object or can be dropped elsewhere as well?

Comment: the circle can be dropped elsewhere too, there are a set of rectangular object. I any of them the circle can be dropped.

Comment: As Ani says, we need a more detailed description of your project, please! What does "attach" mean--are the rect droptargets then permanently inside the dragged circle?  If so, put each circle in its own Kinetic Group and add then attached rects to that circle's Group.  What would "highlight" look like?  You can use rect.setStroke() to change it's stroke color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suppose is that you need to attach the ondrop event handler on the expected target elements and in this attached handler you can write your code for highlighting the target with some change in color or whatever.
I answered this on some assumptions as the question was not clear enough so please bare me if the intention of the question was something else.